# Passing errors to redirected template in views.py in django

Tags: python, django, error-handling

I am using try except to handle errors in views.py.
In the exception area i want to redirect user to a template if there is an error.
While redirecting to the template, i want to pass errors to template and show errors at the beginning of that page.

```
    try:
        car.delete()
    except ProtectedError, e:
        return redirect(reverse('car-operations') + '?car_no=' + str(car.car_no), {'errors': e})
```

The ProtectError occurs when i try to delet the car. But this error is not passed to redirected page. In redicreted page i use below code to show errors.

```
    {% if errors %}<div class="alert alert-danger">{{ errors }}</div>{% endif %}
```

I see that error occurs. But i couldn't pass it to template. If i use render request, i can pass the error to template but this time i can't call the template with "'?car_no=' + str(car.car_no)"

Comment: Use [django.contrib.messages](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/messages/) it allows you to save your messages in request and show it on the next page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is because you can't pass context to redirect,
but for passing the errors to front end you can use something like django message

```
from django.contrib import messages
try:
    car.delete()
except ProtectedError, e:
  messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, e)
```

and in templates to show the error you use this

```
{% if messages %}
<ul class="messages">
   {% for message in messages %}
        <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
 </ul>
    {% endif %}
```

for reference you can check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/messages/

Comment: Perfect sky_1. This was the solution. Thanks alot.